# Determine the cwd of running process, or use a marker to designate process

Tags: shell-script, process, port

I am a software project and I need to have several processes running at once to develop it.

When I start one process using:

```
./scripts/run.sh
```

in that script I want to check if another process is running already, and to determine if it's the correct process, I want to discover what its current working directory is. Is there a way to do that?

Ultimately, I just need some marker that I can use to determine if another necessary process is already running or not, how can I use such a marker?

Using a port or a lockfile or something, would be probably undesirable, but perhaps necessary...

Comment: Essentially I am wondering if I can give a process a name, and then search for it with `ps` etc.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: macos / ubuntu, but mostly just macos

Comment: the PID will vary, I actually just need a static name (that is fairly unique, but won't change)

Comment: It would be cool to give a process a name with an env variable somehow - the OS would give the top level process that name, something like `OS_NAME="foobar" ./scripts/tsc.sh`

Comment: I could use a predesignated port as a lock, and that port  number would be my unique name

Comment: On linux, look around cgroups and namespaces.